# Is there any way to make different potion overlays?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I'm in 1.16.5 optifine and I want to make a custom potion texture and I ran into a problem where the `potion_overlay` texture is used on all 3 types of potions. I want to know is if there is a way to make `potion_overlay` different for each type of potion and I would like to know the code for it. Thanks